# Ruby deprecation warning in URI.parser in a non rails environment when accessing Shopify API

Tags: ruby, shopify

When configuring the Shopify API with authentication credentials in a ruby non-rail environment a deprecation warning occurs.

Here is the minimal code to reproduce it.

Have tested and still fails with the latest api_version 2023-04.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'shopify_api'

API_KEY='my key'
PASSWORD='my password'
SHOP_NAME='my shop name'

shop_url = "https://#{API_KEY}:#{PASSWORD}@#{SHOP_NAME}.myshopify.com/admin"
ShopifyAPI::Base.api_version = '2023-04'
ShopifyAPI::Base.site = shop_url
```

Shopify api version:
../../.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/shopify_api-9.4.1/lib/shopify_api

Ruby version is:
3.1.2

The warning message is:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: URI.parser is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 7.0. Use `URI::DEFAULT_PARSER` instead. (called from  at miniTestConnect.rb:15)

Comment: Would you mind share the Ruby version and the version of the shopify_gem? And the exact deprecation warning message.

Comment: Why use a deprecated API? 2020-10? Use 2022-07 or at least something from 2022.

Comment: Smart money says the warning is "*warning: calling URI.open via Kernel#open is deprecated, call URI.open directly or use URI#open*".

Comment: "Deprecated" is not the same as "depreciated". It means "don't use this, it is going to go away."